# How to set yes/no value to no in a table on a form load to log out all users

Tags: boolean

So I'm creating a ms access database to allow associates to request time off and i need to be able to auto fill a text box based on the user login. that being said, i have a table that has all of the usernames passwords and employee names in it with a yes/no column attached to each user. My question is how can i get the yes/no value to auto set to no when the "login screen" form loads? I want to use the usernames in access not enviorn(username) to get the windows username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My question is how can i get the yes/no value to auto set to no when the "login screen" form loads?"

Create an update query that updates the yes/no field to 0 in table Users (usernames passwords and employee names in it with a yes/no column attached to each user)...name it i.e. ZeroUsersQry

then in the OnLoad event of form login:

docmd.setwarnings false

docmd.openquery "ZeroUsersQry"